# How do I get the row index in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to access a pandas DataFrame with the integer location. 
But how do I get the (original) index of that row?

I tried

```
d1=pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((5, 12)), 
                index=["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"],
                columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "m"])

print(d1.iloc[2].index)
```

I expected a3, but it prints nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need `name`, becasue by `iloc` create `Series`:

```
print(d1.iloc[2])
a    0.0
b    0.0
c    0.0
d    0.0
e    0.0
f    0.0
g    0.0
h    0.0
i    0.0
j    0.0
k    0.0
m    0.0
Name: a3, dtype: float64

print(d1.iloc[2].name)
a3
```

Answer (score 4):

another option:

```
In [99]: d1.index[2]
Out[99]: 'a3'
```